# How to remove white space when iad bannerview has no ad to show

Tags: ios, iphone

Itunes Connect showed me the following error when I submitted my app:

> We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:
>
> - Was not fully optimized to support the device screen size and/or resolution; when the user proceeds to the quiz questions, the app
>     displays a large unused white space at the bottom of the screen that
>     appears to be originally intended for ads. However, at the time of
>     review, no ads are displayed, and this area remains blank, which
>     displays poorly on the user's device.
>
> If there is no intended use for this area, it may be appropriate to
>   ensure that the main UI window for the quiz questions fully fills up
>   the screen for an optimal viewing experience.
>
> This example identifies types of issues discovered in your app but may
>   not represent all such issues. It would be appropriate to thoroughly
>   evaluate your app to address these types of issues.

I have 6 of these applications, and they all have the exact same error. Application only in portrait orientation. I created a simple application test , people answer questions and show the results in the end . All windows are identical , a common background and different questions , one question on one window . At the bottom I attached iad bannerview. I used autolayout for all windows, buttons, labels , etc. On all kinds of simulators advertising is displayed .The app is free and if I remove my ad as offers , the application will not make sense. Maybe there is some option or code that was not a white space where there is no advertising .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's publishing requirements, not a programming problem.

Comment: Advertise on iPhone works too , just may be at the time when the application has not been tested suitable advertising ,and because it does not appear immediately but after a few seconds? P.S. I'm a newbie ?

Comment: It looks like the bug is that the Apple reviewer is not seeing any ads. You should consider changing your question text.

Comment: is it possible to make so that the background was a whole , without the white stripe on advertising if the advertising for any reason temporarily not shown ? I inserted advertisements via interface builder, maybe I need to insert ad code ?

Answer (score 0):

To use iAd, you have to set up iAd in iTunes Connect, and get the iAd Contract. Read more in the tutorial below.

http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/

It shows how to hide the banner when not in use, and how to connect it properly.